# Improve WPF performance with many usercontrols

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I am building my first WPF application and I ran into some performance issues that I am not sure how to deal with. I have a list of around 500 items that I bind to UserControls using an ItemsControl in a Page. The data gets loaded into memory during the program startup and is displayed when the user opens the page. This already takes a few seconds but can be dealt with, however the data can also be reordered (e.g. ascending, descending) and filtered which takes around 0.6-1.3 seconds every time (depending on reordering method used). It seems to be caused by the UI parsing and layout and I was hoping this could be improved somehow. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujMXX.png) is the performance graph in case that helps.

And here is the code of the Item class and associated UserControl xaml (simplified):

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public String content { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage image { get; set; }
        
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private Visibility visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        
        public void LoadImage()
        {
            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 48;
            bitmap.DecodePixelHeight = 48;
            bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(somepath);
            bitmap.EndInit();
            bitmap.Freeze();
            image = bitmap;
        }
        
        public Item()
        {
            LoadImage();
        }
    }
```

```
<UserControl 
    ...
    Visibility="{Binding Path=Visibility}">

    <Grid Background="White"> 
        <Image x:Name="ItemImage" Source="{Binding Path=image}" Width="64" Height="64"></Image>
        <TextBlock x:Name="NameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=name}" FontSize="18px"></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="ContentTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=content}" FontSize="14px" ></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here is the xaml and code of the Page which displays the Usercontrols:

```
<Page>
    <StackPanel x:Name="RootStackPanel">
        <Some static content>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ItemScrollViewer" CanContentScroll="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Width="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="CustomItemsControl">
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

```
public partial class ItemsPage : Page
    {
        public static ItemsPage Instance = new ItemsPage();
        
        public ObservableCollection<Item> collection { get; set; }
        
        // called by a button on the page
        private void ReorderItems()
        {
            // Simplified: Usually more ordering options e.g. OrderByDescending
            List<Item> temp = new List<Item>(collection.OrderBy(item => item.name));
            collection.Clear();
            foreach (Item item in temp)
            {
                collection.Add(item);
            }
        }
        
        public ItemsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            collection = new ObservableCollection<Item>(ItemCollection.GetItems()); 
            // getItems returns the list of items as List<>

            FrameworkElementFactory factoryPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(VirtualizingStackPanel));
            factoryPanel.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.IsItemsHostProperty, true);
            factoryPanel.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingProperty, true);
            factoryPanel.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty, VirtualizationMode.Recycling);
            ItemsPanelTemplate template = new ItemsPanelTemplate();
            template.VisualTree = factoryPanel;
            CustomItemsControl.ItemsPanel = template;

            FrameworkElementFactory dataTemplateFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ItemUserControl));
            DataTemplate dataTemplate = new DataTemplate();
            dataTemplate.VisualTree = dataTemplateFactory;
            CustomItemsControl.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
            
            CustomItemsControl.ItemsSource = collection;
        }
    }
```

As can be seen I tried using Virtualization but I am not sure if I am using it correctly since I saw no measurable performance gain. The pictured reordering method is obviously not ideal since I alternatively tried reordering the members of the items instead and calling the PropertyChangedEventHandler on the bound members. This did improve performance by getting rid of the parsing step but still takes 600ms on average per reorder. Are there better methods to do that or should I be trying to simplify my UserControls instead?

Comment: You may want to use a [CollectionView for sorting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#binding-to-collections). Besides that, it's unclear why you are setting the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel in code behind and not in XAML, as usual.

Comment: 600 ms is not so bad. It's less than 1 second. That's too slow? I do notice that you load your images from an url. Is that local or some remote server?

Comment: Well I hoped it could be improved some more since you can still feel the delay when using it. As for the images: they get loaded from disk but it is done when the program starts so I dont think it should affect runtime performance

Comment: You should use a listbox rather than an itemscontrol in a scrollviewer. Rather than add each entry to an observablecollection i would  instantiate a new one passing your sorted list to the observablecollection ctor.  And bind that to itemssource from a viewmodel implements inotifypropertychanged. I think all at once is usually faster than numerous change notifications.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a ScrollViewer around ItemsControl Virtualization will not work.
extract ItemsControl from ScrollViewer.